# how to identify the login details from data base

Tags: asp.net

i created a signup page and enter those values in database. Now i want to create a login page and have to check the details from the data base, whether the user registered or not? How can any one help me...please?

Comment: Have you googled for this before you are posting if so means you can find many

Comment: @Dorababu...thanks for your suggestion, but here we can find answers in more appropriate way and in clearly... but unfortunately my questions are becoming single....its very strange...

Comment: A lot of sites available for .Net codes sample are csharpcorner.com, Asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any way i will give you a basic idea

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SYSTEM1;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string sql;
        sql = "select *from user1 where uname ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and pwd = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Response.Redirect("User.aspx");


        }
 }
```

This is just an idea you can implement in more secure way

Comment: @Thank you... i think you are telugu person.. avna..!

Comment: Ok ok this is not the place to chat bye